# kotlin-parcelize showing Auto-build Error

Tags: android, kotlin

Well after trying a lot to solve the error own my own, I think the last thing to try is stack overflow.

I am having a problem due to **kotlin-parcelize showing error in Auto-build** and don't have any idea about how to solve It.

Well before It I was trying to upgrader the **version of Kotlin to 1.4.31** and also changed the **JCenter()** to **mavenCenteral()**.

Can anyone tell if I importing Kotlin wrongly or doing something else which is causing the problem

**build.gradle**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0-beta06'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.4"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle(:app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            storeFile file('D:\\mohit\\Desktop\\ChatApp\\app\\debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'A123456'
            keyAlias 'key0'
            keyPassword 'A123456'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.chatapp"
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
        viewBinding true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    // kotlin-stdlib (there was a issue with the versioning that's why excluded and included again kotlin-stdlib-jdk7)
    implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"){
        exclude group:"org.jetbrains.kotlin", module: "kotlin-stdlib-jdk7"
    }
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    // Kotlin lang
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'

    // Appcompat and UI
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'

    // Material Design
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'

    // Import the Firebase BoM
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.0.0')

    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies

    // Declare the dependency for the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'

    // ConstraintLayout
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'

    // View Pager
    implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0"

    // Annotation
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0'
    // LiveData
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    // ViewModel
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    // Lifecycle Only
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'

    // RxJava and RxAndroid
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.5"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0"

    // Navigation
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.4'

    // Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    // ******** //

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'

    // CameraX core library
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:1.1.0-alpha03"

    // CameraX Camera2 extensions
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.1.0-alpha03"

    // CameraX Lifecycle Library
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.1.0-alpha03"

    // CameraX View class
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha23"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.6"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.6"

    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.6"



    // Local BroadcastManager
    implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

**Error Auto-build**

```
Error:Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.lang.IllegalStateException: The provided plugin org.jetbrains.kotlin.parcelize.ParcelizeComponentRegistrar is not compatible with this version of compiler

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.registerExtensionsFromPlugins$cli(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:592)

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$ProjectEnvironment.registerExtensionsFromPlugins(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:132)

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:172)

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt)

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:426)

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:226)

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:152)

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1500)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)

    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)

    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)

    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)

    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)

    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)

    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)

    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)

    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)

    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)

    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)

    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.jetbrains.kotlin.parcelize.ParcelizeComponentRegistrar does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void registerProjectComponents(com.intellij.mock.MockProject, org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.CompilerConfiguration)' of interface org.jetbrains.kotlin.compiler.plugin.ComponentRegistrar.

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.registerExtensionsFromPlugins$cli(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:584)

    ... 28 more
```

[image: Image Showing Error]

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Yeah it was nothing but because I changed some settings and turn on auto build and that's why it was causing error.

Comment: can you tell what actually you changed?